# jQuery dataTable : IE formatting issue for next button

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am having issues fixing the pagination next button in IE using jquery.dataTable. It would be helpful if anyone could give me an headsup on this.

Its overflowing the footer of the table.

Comment: Hey @Abhi, did you ever solve this? Otherwise, try to place some code. If you solved it, you could post an answer and accept it, perhaps helping other people in the future. Yes, I know it is a very old question :)